# Windows 8 automatically recognising hardware?

Tags: windows-8, drivers

After using other operating system for some years I went back to Windows with Windows 8. To my surprise, everything (or most of it) worked out of the box, without any drivers from the manufacturers. Is that because Windows 8 ships with generic ones? I installed the RealTek audio and graphics card driver anyway but didn't install any chipset or WiFi ones.

Can you please clear me up on this? Is Windows now providing fully supported drivers for many hardware configuration by default, so it is unnecessary to install the drivers from the manufacturer? How about the chipset driver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft has aggressively tried to include many hardware drivers from the manufacturers, as well as the chipset drivers.  As in XP and Win7, this isn't likely to be the absolute latest driver, and won't work with hardware introduced after the OS release, but it certainly should be able to handle something as common as RealTek audio.  Consider it similar to installing a printer in XP -- most of the very common (popular) printer drivers were included.  Part of this process is when the manufacturer submits their product for certification with Win8.

Comment: What they did with printer drivers was really interesting.  beyond the generic device drivers they already had for input devices they came up with a new driver model specifically for drivers.  Now they don't add support for say duplex or special fonts but in general a printer will print a page with these drivers.  This also allows future printer drivers to be built off this base driver so the overall size of "printing software' can reduce by ten fold.